# Mac Application bottom bar add button

Tags: macos, cocoa, button

I added a bottom bar on `NSWindow` in IB by select "Content Border-Large Bottom Border". And I  add a custom Image button on the bottom bar, but when I press the button, the background of the button turns into white, why?

This is the effect when press down the button:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change button's type to ***Momentary Change***. You can change it in Attributes inspector:

[image: how to do it]

Or change programatically:

```
[button setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
```